# Usage of Assembly.LoadModule

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

How to use this method?

[Assembly.LoadModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5713xtes(v=VS.100).aspx)

I am creating an assembly in runtime using Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly...

I want to know how can I load this assembly created in runtime in an existing assembly defined in design time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it sounds like your are trying to load a dynamically created `Assembly` into an `Assembly` which is defined on disk by the developer.  Is that correct?

If so this is simply not possible.  Assemblies once defined are effectively immutable.  Their type information can't change at run time.  Modules can't be pushed into them afterwards.

Can you give us a bit more detail on what you're trying to achieve here?  Perhaps there is another solution.

Comment: Thanks! I am building repositories in runtime, I am using NHibernate, and I use Windsor to inject this repositories in my Controller(ASP.NET MVC) I was using Widson with TypeFromAssembly convetion. I did it using another way passing all types that I want, so thats fine, I just  want to know if I could add types in disk assembly to use last convention.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to load it. You have just created it, so it is already loaded. All you need to do now is create a ModuleBuilder with `AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule()`, create your classes in it, and start using them.

Comment: But I want to load this module created in runtime in another Assembly that is not dynamic